# Has Microsoft discussed whether future versions of SharePoint will support MVC?

Tags: development, visual-studio

I haven't heard anything about whether they will be including this in the future or not.  I did some Googling and found an [interesting project on CodePlex](http://sharepointmvc.codeplex.com/) but did not find anything official from Microsoft.  Has anyone heard anything reliable about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing has been shared on SharePoint vNext, so right now only speculations and wild guesses can be made.

I doubt SharePoint will be converted to an MVC model, to much legacy in this product.

Comment: I agree with Wictor.  It is doubtful that SharePoint will go the MVC route anytime soon each version (at least 2007 and 2010) have maintained similar object model and database structures to the previous version.  Going that route would re-do how SharePoint does it's most basic functions and would break backwards-compatibility.